# Why does my custom token show 0?

Tags: mist, tokens

I created a vanilla custom token via a contract on testnet and minted 10,000 coins to it, and I was able to successfully send the tokens to a wallet contract at a different address. However, when I attempt to use the `Watch Token` feature and paste the contract address, the balance is always zero, despite the form auto-loading the other contract variables.

Shouldn't the number next to the icon display the amount of custom tokens associated with the main account address?

I am using Mist 0.8.10 on ropsten testnet.

[image: Custom Token]
[image: Contract details]

My contract is pretty simple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract PractCoin {

    mapping (address => uint256) public monies;
    address public owner;
    uint public totalCoins;
    uint public initialSupply;
    string public name;
    uint8 decimalPlaces;

    function PractCoin(uint _totalCoins, uint _initialSupply, string _name, uint8 _decimalPlaces){
        owner = msg.sender;
        totalCoins = _totalCoins;
        initialSupply = _initialSupply;
        monies[owner] = initialSupply;
        name = _name;
        decimalPlaces = _decimalPlaces;
    }

    function sendCoins(address _to, uint _amount){
        if (monies[msg.sender] < _amount || 
            msg.sender == _to || 
            monies[_to] + _amount < _amount) throw;
        monies[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        monies[_to] += _amount;
        CoinTransfer(_amount, _to, msg.sender);
    }

    function destroyContract(){
        if (msg.sender == owner ) selfdestruct(owner);
        ContractDestroyed("Contract Destroyed!");

    }

    event CoinTransfer(uint _amount, address indexed _to, address indexed _from);
    event ContractDestroyed(string _message);
}
```

Comment: Yes ok i am very happy this and i intresst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your contract is not [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) compliant. It is very important to retain the ERC20 standard, which means keeping all names the same. See [this definition contract](https://github.com/GridPlus/contracts/blob/master/ERC20.sol). Mist should be looking for the following properties, per ERC20:

```
uint public supply;
string public name;
uint8 public decimals;
string public symbol;
string public version;
```

You should also include **all** of the following functions to be ERC20 compliant:

```
function totalSupply() constant returns (uint) {
  return supply;
}

function balanceOf( address who ) constant returns (uint) {
  return balances[who];
}

function transfer( address to, uint value) returns (bool) {
  balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], value);
  balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], value);
  Transfer( msg.sender, to, value );
  return true;
}

function transferFrom( address from, address to, uint value) returns (bool) {
  approvals[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(approvals[from][msg.sender], value);
  balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], value);
  balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], value);
  Transfer( from, to, value );
  return true;
}

function approve(address spender, uint value) returns (bool) {
  approvals[msg.sender][spender] = value;
  Approval( msg.sender, spender, value );
  return true;
}

function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint) {
  return approvals[owner][spender];
}
```