# Custom token showing balance of 0 in MyEtherWallet

Tags: solidity, tokens, myetherwallet

I made a new token on the Ropsten test network. Here's the contract address: 0x801fd9c17087ec868dc8540055b7ea3cb6dbbe34.

When I followed the instructions to add this custom token to MyEtherWallet (by specifying the contract address, symbol and correct number of decimals), I see that my ICICB token is added to the token list. However, the balance says 0, even though I have sent some tokens to my address. Also, when I try to select the ICICB token from the dropdown menu to send it, it doesn't show up (just Eth shows up).

When you look at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x411724F571e83D5fa74d42462F0cAFBddDfed5fc which is my MyEtherWallet address, you can see that is has 2,000,000 ICICB tokens.

Could you please explain to me what's going on? Maybe I'm missing something.

I also, looked at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18863/why-does-my-custom-token-show-0) thread, but it seems to me that my token is ERC20 compliant, as I have all of the necessary functions.

Here's my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 'ICICB' token contract
//
// Deployed to : 0x9f7bb2e565F94C3FF3e365eb95cAF73b458b2149
// Symbol      : ICICB
// Name        : ICICB Token
// Total supply: 100000000
// Decimals    : 18
//
// Enjoy.
// (c) by Moritz Neto with BokkyPooBah / Bok Consulting Pty Ltd Au 2017. The MIT Licence.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe maths
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call
//
// Borrowed from MiniMeToken
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Owned contract
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract Owned {
    address public owner;
    address public newOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }
    function acceptOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = address(0);
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and assisted
// token transfers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ICICBToken is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() public {
        symbol = "ICICB";
        name = "ICICB Token";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
        balances[0x9f7bb2e565F94C3FF3e365eb95cAF73b458b2149] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), 0x9f7bb2e565F94C3FF3e365eb95cAF73b458b2149, _totalSupply);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account tokenOwner
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to to account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer tokens from the from account to the to account
    // 
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the from account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account. The spender contract function
    // receiveApproval(...) is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Don't accept ETH
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function () public payable {
        revert();
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you chose the ropsten network in MEW ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. This is the address: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x411724F571e83D5fa74d42462F0cAFBddDfed5fc#tokentxns that I use. The same address I see in MEW, and I changed to the ropsten testnet, I have a different address for the main network.

Comment: You were right. Even though I switched to the ropsten network on my phone I still needed to do the same on my pc. What was confusing is that the PC was showing the ropsten ETH address when I switched to the ropsten network on mobile and scanned the QR code, but it still used the mainnet

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used MEW on desktop, and even though I selected the Ropsten testnet on my phone, I needed to select it on my desktop also. This is kinda confusing because the ETH address that was displayed on my desktop version was the Ropsten address (because I switched to it on my phone before scanning the QR code to connect), but for some reason I had to manually set the network on desktop too.

[image]
[image]